# Unexpected line Turtle Module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I know it is kinda a silly question but I was working on this small side project that takes data from a api and then uses a library to map that out. It ultimately displays the position of the International Space Station on the map(PNG files).

```
import json, turtle, urllib.request, time, webbrowser
import geocoder # this will do lat/long work

#getting names of astros aboard
url = "http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())
a = open("iss.txt","w")
a.write("There are currently" + str(result["number"])+"astronauts aboard the ISS:\n\n")

people = result["people"]

for p in people:
    a.write(p["name"]+ " - on board" + "\n")

g = geocoder.ip('me')

a.write("\nYour current Lat/Long is: " + str(g.latlng)) # prints your lat/long in txt file
a.close()
webbrowser.open("iss.txt")

#setup world map
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(1280, 866)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180 ,90)
# load the image
screen.bgpic("map.gif")

screen.register_shape("iss_image.gif")
iss = turtle.Turtle()
iss.shape("iss_image.gif")
iss.setheading(45)
iss.penup

while True:
    # load real time status
    url = "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    result = json.loads(response.read())

    #extract iss location
    location = result["iss_position"]
    lat = location["latitude"]
    lon = location["longitude"]

    #output lat and long to console
    lat = float(lat)
    lon = float(lon)
    print("\nLatitude: " + str(lat))
    print("Longitude: " + str(lon))

    #update iss location
    iss.goto(lon, lat)[enter image description here][1]
    #refresh every 5 secs
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what's the question you are trying to ask?

Comment: No problem, figured it out. Thanks

Comment: @AKD Please post an answer for potential future viewers!